# BCP data import, invalid time format error

Tags: sql-server, datetime, bcp, bulk-import

I have failed to load a text file's data to my db's table with the persistent error

invalid time format.

I have changed the time format to include a T between the date and time, to no avail. I also substituted the year, month, date delimiter from . to - but the error persisted.

This is how I am attempting to load from a txt file

```
bcp mydb.dbo.mytable in c:\data.txt -T -S myserver\instance
```

I then proceed to confirm data types of the fields, prefix-length (this is the length of the delimiter before the field... right?) and the field terminator. I create a format file which when used still yields the same error. The datetime field I am importing is one of four other fields in a typical row.

What am I missing?

EDIT

Here is a typical row

```
14,1999-01-04T08:08:24.000,1.36000,1.36000
```

I have also failed when using SSIS my prior work around of first using access is not applicable here. It is either bcp or SSIS

Comment: Include a little sample of data please.

Comment: What you are missing? Don't know... But I can tell you what I am missing: Sample data, some lines of your "typical rows". And one hint: Try your statement with a file which holds just the first few lines. it could be, that one single date somewhere down there is bad and not the format itself. And another hint: Most problems occur with differing month-day-order. 2016-04-01 will work, but might produce unexpected results, 2016-13-04 won't work...

Comment: Got this to work via SSIS... guess bcp is an antique ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using `SQL Server 2008 (R2)`? If so, please add appropriate tag to your question.

This problem has been reported [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/bcp-in-of-datetime-type-data-results-in-an-invalid-date-time-format) at *dba.stackexchange*.

Following hints were given:

- You need to use a generated format file and use `-f` for both import and export.
- Ensure your datetimes are formatted like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, so with a space instead of a `T` in between date and time

Note that I read [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic976437-391-1.aspx) the claim that this is a bug in `BCP` that ships with `SQL Server 2008 (R2)`. Apparantly this was solved in `SQL Server 2012`+.

Comment: Hi, was using SQL 2014... Had to resort to first importing txt file into access then exporting the accdb file to SQL